# Strange behaviour of audio output through HDMI

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, vlc

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I've connected my AV-receiver via HDMI to my laptop. The video output through HDMI seems to work quite well, however I have the following issue with the HDMI audio output:

When I restart my computer and immediately test the speakers via HDMI output (in the system settings) they work, also when I watch a *video* file (say .mkv for example) through the VLC player, the audio still works perfectly.
If I have a video running via VLC and mute it, then the audio in other applications still works fine.

But if there is *no* video playing in VLC, then the HDMI audio output does not work in any other application. So, for example I don't get audio when watching a youtube video, or even when I try to play an audio file via VLC I don't have sound.

How can I fix the HDMI audio output so that it works for all applications?

I don't have a lot of experience with ubuntu, but this issue seems quite weird to me.

Thanks a lot for any help!

(By the way, if I select the audio output through the internal laptop speakers or headphones everything works fine. But as soon as I select the HDMI output I get the problem above)